# How to forcibly create stored procedure even if some error occurs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I execute database script, I got errors in stored procedure then it couldn't create that stored procedure that have errors. I want to forcibly create stored procedure even if some error occur in stored procedure.

If some error occurred in the create procedure statement it won't create stored procedure. What I want is that stored procedure will be created anyway, whether an error occurred or not.

Actually we have database in SQL Server 2000, I attached it in SQL Server 2005 and then change the compatibility level to 90. And finally I want to execute the script but I also want that if some error occurred then it will ignore error and create the objects.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of the error in the first place?  Something's obviously gone wrong with your code.  Fix it, and then the stored proc will be created just fine.  Why not paste the code here so we can help you?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would want to create a broken stored procedure anyway?

Comment: Maybe if a table doesn't exist at the time the stored procedure is created.

Comment: if the table doesn't exist it should still work fine. it just won't check that the columns are valid. same if a dependency is missing - it will just print a message (mssql). if it's got a syntax error then it shouldn't work. just like you can't compile broken code.

Comment: Do you want to focibly create the proc with the wrong code (which you can't) or an empty proc if there is an error (which you may with some exception handling)?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some background on why you want to do this? It might help with the answers.

Comment: Extremely bad idea. Do not attempt to put bad code into your database. There is a reason for those errors. Fix the code.

Comment: In my case we are creating global temp tables and referencing those within the stored proc. However the alter proc fails if the global temp table does not exist since the fields are being referenced. When I have to make updates on 200 procs like this THEN you see the need for saving a proc EVEN IF it has errors. Because I know at run-time it won't fail.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the creation of a stored procedure by creating it in a can't-fail way.  See this example:

```
if object_id('sp_name') is null
    exec sp_executesql N'create procedure dbo.sp_name as select 1'
go
alter procedure db.sp_name
as
...
go
```

Now if the alter fails, there will be a stored procedure anyway.